# React-redux rerender action type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Need to implement simple logic to switch the state of the buttons depending on the redux data. Initially, all buttons are true, but when I click on the Approve button, I send a request to the server, I get a response (false) and disabled button, then when I click on the Decline button, the Approve button should change the state to true, and Decline the button to false etc.

[image: img]

When I click on the decline button a second time, it returns state where approval is returned, how i can return a new state each time

**Action**

```
//Approve candidate
export const approveRequest = (token, id) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'FETCHING_ON' });
    try {
        axios.post(API.approveCandidateRequest + '/' + id,
            {},
            {headers: {"Authorization": 'Bearer ' + token.token }})
            .then( (response) => {
                if ( response.status === 200) {
                    dispatch(approveAction(response.data));
                }
            });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
};

//Decline Candidate
export const declineRequest = (token, id) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'FETCHING_OFF' });
    try {
        axios.post(API.declineCandidateRequest + '/' + id,
            {},
            {headers: {"Authorization": 'Bearer ' + token.token }})
            .then( (response) => {
                if ( response.status === 200) {
                    dispatch( declineAction( response.data) );
                }
            });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
};
```

**Reducer**

```
case 'SET_DECLINE_DATA_STATUS':
    return {
        ...state,
        isDecline: action.isDecline,
        mergeDeclineDataToMessage: state.me.messages.push(action.isDecline.data.message)
    };
case 'FETCHING_ON':
    return {
        ...state,
        isDecline: null
    };
case 'SET_APPROVE_DATA_STATUS':
    return {
        ...state,
        isApprove: action.isApprove,
        mergeApproveToMessage: state.me.messages.push(action.isApprove.data.message)
    };
case 'FETCHING_OFF':
    return {
        ...state,
        isApprove: null
    };
```

**Logic**

```
const ShareContacts = ( { messages, getProfileShare, declineRequest, isDecline, isApprove, approveRequest } ) => {

    const shared = messages.me ? messages.me.account.shared : null;
    const id = messages.me ? messages.me.account.id : null;

    const [ roleId, setRoleId ] = useState('');
    const [ token, setToken ] = useState('');

    let declineIsDisabled = false;
    let approveIsDisabled = false;


    if ( isApprove  && isApprove.data.is_approved !== null && isApprove.data.is_approved !== undefined
        && isApprove.data.is_approved === true ) {
        approveIsDisabled = true;
        declineIsDisabled = !approveIsDisabled;
        console.log('isApprove', 1);
    }

    if (isDecline  && isDecline.data.is_approved !== null && isDecline.data.is_approved !== undefined
        && isDecline.data.is_approved === false ) {
        declineIsDisabled = true;
        approveIsDisabled = !declineIsDisabled;
        console.log('isDecline', 2)
    }

    isDecline = isApprove = null;


    useEffect( () => {
       const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user-data"));
        getProfileShare(token);
        setRoleId(token.roleId);
        setToken(token)
    }, []);

    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const openModal = () => {
        setOpen(true);
    };
    const closeModal = () => {
        setOpen(false);
    };

    const handleApproveRequest = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        approveRequest(token, id);
    };

    const handleDeclineRequest = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        declineRequest(token, id)
    };

   return(
        <ShareButtons>
            {
                roleId === 1 ? !shared ? (<Button size='tiny' color='green' onClick={openModal}>Share Contact</Button>) : null
                    : roleId === 2 ? shared ? (
                        <Flex>
                            <Button size='tiny' disabled={ approveIsDisabled }
                                  onClick={handleApproveRequest}   color='green'>Approve</Button>
                            <Button size='tiny' disabled={ declineIsDisabled }
                                    onClick={handleDeclineRequest}  color='red'>Decline</Button>
                            <Button size='tiny'  color='grey' onClick={openModal}>Open Contacts</Button>
                        </Flex>
                    ) : null :null  
            }
            {
                roleId === 1 ? (<UserDataModal open={open} closeModal={closeModal} /> )
                    : roleId === 2 ? ( <RecruiterDataModal id={id} open={open} closeModal={closeModal} /> ) : null
            }

        </ShareButtons>
    );
};
```

Comment: I would separate storing on server and your Redux store. So you would update the store directly and do the request afterwards. If the request or approval fails you could change the state back. This way your app is more responsive as the state changes immediately. I would also check [Redux-Saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial.html) to do the server requests - easier for writing tests. You can find a demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-microservice-t7zkl).

Comment: @AWolf Thanks fot feedback, but i can do this method without saga ?

Comment: Sure, you don't need sagas. But you could separate concerns better. Anyway, I think I don't understand your problem. Can you please explain what's not working and how it should work? Is the first click working and the second one is not working?